# What could cause network lag (after latest update)

Tags: 11.04, networking

I got very different timings from script accessing gdata (Google servers) on Windows and Ubuntu on same machine and thought to compare `ping google.com` results:

[image]

x-axis: packets
y-axis: ms

---

> Ping statistics for Windows 7:
>       Packets: Sent = 100, Received = 100, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
>   Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
>       Minimum = 54ms, Maximum = 107ms, Average = 57ms

---

> --- google.com ping statistics Ubuntu 11.04 ---
>   100 packets transmitted, 99 received, +4 duplicates, 1% packet loss, time 107550ms
>   rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 49.688/451.811/2436.608/532.491 ms, pipe 3

---

What could couse this lag?
I suspect that it's latest kernel update which was yesterday (2.6.38-12-generic), as I think everything was fine before last update, but I'm not sure
Also, please feel free to ask for data, as I'm relatively new Linux user, and Linux network is foreign to me

---

**edit 1**: Here is output from **iwconfig**

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bg  ESSID:"home"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: 00:1F:9F:71:82:AF   
          Bit Rate=48 Mb/s   Tx-Power=27 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=39/100  Signal level=39/100  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:383  Invalid misc:93   Missed beacon:0
```

Comment: boot into an older kernel and rerun your tests to confirm

Comment: It's same with older (2.6.38-8) kernel, so it's not kernel update but some recent update. I browsed `syslog` and this log line: `kernel: handle_rx_packet: invalid, small RX packet : 1` seems like it's repeating from when this issue started.

Comment: I also unplugged USB wifi adapter then plugged again, but it's same. Accessing Internet from Ubuntu is frustrating right now. I'll switch to Windows and add bounty for resolving.

Answer (score 1):

"Solution" was trivial: I reset main router (to which I connect with USB adapter) and now everything is back to normal.
Great driver :? If I could only knew this before spending time on resolving what I don't understand...